# URLSession caching not working as documented - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, urlsession

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy) if you use the default `useProtocolCachePolicy` the logic is as follows:

> 1. If a cached response does not exist for the request, the URL loading system fetches the data from the originating source.
> 2. Otherwise, if the cached response does not indicate that it must be revalidated every time, and if the cached response is not stale (past its expiration date), the URL loading system returns the cached response.
> 3. If the cached response is stale or requires revalidation, the URL loading system makes a HEAD request to the originating source to see if the resource has changed. If so, the URL loading system fetches the data from the originating source. Otherwise, it returns the cached response.

However, my experimentation (see below) has shown this to be completely false. Even if the response is cached it is *never* used, and no `HEAD` request is *ever* made.

## Scenario

I am making a request to a URL that returns `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers which never change. I have made the request at least once so the response is already cached (which I can verify by looking at the cache DB for the app on the iOS simulator)

#### Using `useProtocolCachePolicy` (the default)

If I have a `URLSession` with a `URLSessionConfiguration` with `requestCachePolicy` set to `useProtocolCachePolicy` then the response *is* cached (I can see it in the cache DB), but the cached response is never used. Repeated requests to the same URL always make a new `GET` request *without* `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` headers, so the server always returns HTTP 200 with the full response. The cached response is ignored.

#### Using `reloadRevalidatingCacheData` on every `URLRequest`

If I set the `cachePolicy` on *each* `URLRequest` to `reloadRevalidatingCacheData` then I see caching in action. Each time I make the request, a `GET` request is made with the `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers set to the values of the `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers, respectively, of the cached response. As nothing has changed, the server responds with a `304 Not Modified`, and the locally cached response is returned to the caller.

#### Using `reloadRevalidatingCacheData` only on the `URLSessionConfiguration`

If I only set `requestCachePolicy = . reloadRevalidatingCacheData` on the `URLSessionConfiguration` (instead of on each `URLRequest`) then when the app starts only the *first* request uses cache headers and gets a `304 Not Modified` response. Subsequent requests are normal GET requests without any cache headers.

### Conclusion

All the other cache policy settings are basically variants of "only use cached data" or "never use the cache" so are not relevant here.

There is **no** scenario in which `URLSession` makes a `HEAD` request as the documentation claims, and no situation in which it just uses cached data without revalidation based on expiration date information in the original response.

The workaround I will use is to set `cachePolicy = .reloadRevalidatingCacheData` on **every** `URLRequest` to get some level of local caching, as `304 Not Modified` response only return headers and no data so there is a saving of network traffic.

If anyone as any better solutions, or knows how to get `URLSession` working as documented, then I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

Service response headers should include:

> Cache-Control: must-revalidate

Apple will use this instruction to implement *.useProtocolCachePolicy* as described in documentation.